# How to access underlying raw field of an Interface in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I'm a bit new to TypeScript and wondering how can I access the raw field of a Class that extends an Interface?

e.g.

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders {
    [name: string]: string | undefined;
}

getMap(headers: APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders): Map<string, string> {
    const map: Map<string, string> = headers.getUnderlyingMap();
    return map;
}
```

So I want some nice way to achieve what that imaginary `headers.getUnderlyingMap()` call aims to do?

I'm not sure what the type of  `[name: string]: string | undefined` is?

Is it some special TypeScript construct? All I seem to be able to do is `headers["xxx"]`.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the help, I was able to just do this to achieve what I wanted:

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders {
    [name: string]: string | undefined;
}

export class InternalEvent {

    constructor(
        public reqHeaders: {}) {
    }

    static fromInternalEvent(headers: APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders): InternalEvent {
        return new InternalEvent(headers);
    }

}
```

Comment: `I'm not sure what the type of [name: string]: string | undefined is?` It is a string indexed object that allows for values to be of type `string` or `undefined`.

Comment: OK thanks Mike! So how do I extract it into it's own variable?

Comment: Please edit your question since it's not quite clear where or what the problem is with your code or what you are trying to do with it

Comment: "*access the raw field of a Class*" - they're just that, raw properties of a class instance. Plain object properties. There is no "underlying map" or something.

Comment: Can't understand, whys this question is downvoted? @user1974753 provided an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat this type `[name: string]: string | undefined` as an object (dictionary), where all keys are strings and values are either string or undefined.

Here you have several examples to understand it better:

```js
interface Dictionary {
  [name: string]: string | undefined
}

const x: Dictionary = {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe'
} // ok

const y: Dictionary = {
  name: 'John',
  1: 'hello'
} // ok, because JS make coersion under the hood, so you can acces x['1']

/**
 * Indexed types are more generic, because you can use any key you want
 */

y['any key I want'] // valid, returns undefined
y['()=>{}'] // like I said, any key)


const z: Dictionary = {
  name: 23
} // error, value can be either string or undefined, but not number
```

Comment: The second one will fail in TypeScript, because the index type has to be a string.

Comment: @JoshWulf do yoo mean y['1'] ? No, TS will not fail, because of JS coersion.

Comment: Ah, I thought the attempt to explicitly construct it wouldn't transpile. But you're right. I tested it, and it does the coercion.

Comment: Some time ago, it was a surprise for me. I did not believe it either )))

Answer (score 1):

`APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders` is an object, like this:

```
{
  key1: "somevalue",
  key2: "someothervalue",
  key3: undefined
}
```

That interface definition for the object means that you will need to test both the existence of a key, and the presence of a value. If both are true, then you have a string.

Like this:

```
// const obj: APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders

if (!!obj[key]) {
  // obj[key] is a string
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  // obj[key] is string | undefined
}
```

You can convert this object into an Map like this:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj))
```

Now you have a Map with the values in it. But there is not much advantage to this, because you don't have any additional type information - just a different data structure.

Comment: Simpler: `new Map(Object.entries(obj))`

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a convenience method for this!